# What are the corresponding testing-library/react versions for react 16.8.6?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to make a typescript frontend but I can't use the `react-dom/client` import because of an issue that I've narrowed down to my testing-library/react version not corresponding with my react version. I've tried multiple downgraded versions but can't seem to get it to work.

Is there any solutions to this? I'll attach my `package.json` file below.

```js
{
  "name": "balls",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "12.1.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.35",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "@vercel/node": "^1.15.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",
    "vercel": "^24.2.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 27):

Looking at the peer dependencies of [package.json of the version 12 of react-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/blob/v12.1.5/package.json#L63-L64) we can say that until version `12.*`, `react-testing-library` supports any `react` version before `react 18`. As of [`react-testing-library 13`](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/blob/v13.0.0/package.json#L63-L64), it requires `react 18`.

So to answer the question, at the time of writing, you can use `react-testing-library 12.1.5` with `react 16.8.6`.

Comment: I'm very glad that some else ran into this specific issue. your answer helped me a lot