# Which versions of testing-library are compatible with which versions of React?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have encountered a (now known) bug with @testing-library/user-event version 12.8.3 and need to upgrade to a newer version. I'm wondering how high a version can I go?

We're using react-dom 16.8.5, and rather than just plugging in the latest version of testing library I was hoping to see a compatibility list somewhere. Is there such a thing? I can't seem to glean anything from npmjs.com.

Comment: This might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72264785/what-are-the-corresponding-testing-library-react-versions-for-react-16-8-6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the corresponding testing-library/react versions for react 16.8.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72264785/what-are-the-corresponding-testing-library-react-versions-for-react-16-8-6)

Comment: Yes, but React really ought to make it easier to find what goes with what